# Issuse with the Winformexample SharpPcap Addapter

Tags: adapter, capture, sharppcap

How do I refresh the list of adapters in C#?

Say the following happens:

- List device and I see the device.
- I unplug and replug in WITHOUT starting the software.
- the device changes from: `\\.\airpcap00 AirPcap USB wireless capture adapter nr. 00` to
  `\\.\airpcap01 AirPcap USB wireless capture adapter nr. 01`
- but the list of devices still seems to show: `\\.\airpcap00 AirPcap USB wireless capture adapter nr. 00`

How do I refresh the device to show the correct list?

Answer (score 0):

Use WinPcapDeviceList.Instance.Refresh() or AirPcapDeviceList or LibPcapDeviceList to refresh the list.

Comment: Hi Chris, Many thanks got an email from you also, that works 100%, great work